# VBA Loop to find a duplicate of color in a specific range

Tags: vba, excel

I've been looking around for a generic code and modify but I am not able to solve my problem.

I have a working file including many rows. Each line is supposed to have only one color fill `(RGB 0,204,0)`. I would like to know if it possible to automatically loop (without using action button) into my document and highlight the rows via MsgBox in which I have the same color.

Thanks !

Comment: should your code run on `Worksheet_Change()` event?

Comment: To answer your question, yes that is possible.

Comment: even if it was not possible, @L42 tells while the difficult takes time, the impossible just takes a little longer :) cheers mate

Answer (score 0):

I recorded a macro to see what is the code of **RGB(0,204,0)** and I found that it's **52224**.

Now I assumed that *your Worksheet name* is `Sheet1` and the *name of your Specific Range* is `MySpecificRange`

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChangeTheColorofSpecificRange()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim MyRange As Range

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set MyRange = Range("MySpecificRange")

        If MyRange.Interior.Color <> 52224 Then
           MsgBox "Your SpecificRange doesn't have your desired background color so I'm going to do it!"
           MyRange.Interior.Color = 52224
        End If
End Sub
```

After you write this code in your module, you can run this by clicking F5 or either go to `Developer` tab, `Macros` section and `Run` the macro.

---

As long as question is not enough clear, here are some another possible solutions:

---

If you are looking for `Worksheet_Change()` event as @*Romcel Geluz* asked, please copy below code into your `Worksheet` object page.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim MyRange As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set MyRange = Range("MySpecificRange")

    If MyRange.Interior.Color <> 52224 Then
        MsgBox "Your SpecificRange doesn't have your desired background color so I'm going to do it!"
        MyRange.Interior.Color = 52224
    End If
End Sub
```

In this example, whatever you do/type/change in your worksheet, if your SpecificRange is not in your desired color, it will change it with that.(And inform you with the fancy MsgBox!)

---

Or if you want some code to change the background color of your SpecificRange at the beginning of your workbook, when you open it, copy this below code to the `ThisWorkbook` sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim MyRange As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set MyRange = Range("MySpecificRange")

    If MyRange.Interior.Color <> 52224 Then
        MsgBox "Your SpecificRange doesn't have your desired background color so I'm going to do it!"
        MyRange.Interior.Color = 52224
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The proper way to use color values is with `MyRange.Interior.Color = RGB(0,204,0)`. You can assign RGB Values to vars by defining them as `Long` and use the same mehtod.

Comment: Thank you very much Mertinc! 

My range is (C27:G48) 

However, I was wondering if the following can be done : when the loop is going to find the specific color (0,204,0), it's going to look the text of the cell : i.e. EXCELLENT (80) and copy/paste the numerical value into the col H. My numbers are going from 0 ; 5; 20 ; 40 ; 60 ; 80 ; 100. 

If the loop find two cells with the color (0,204,0) the B column need to be colored (0,0,255) 

Finnaly, if the result in the specific text is 0, the col H related need to be colored in (255,0,0).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much @Mertinc

My range is (C27:G48)

However, I was wondering if the following can be done : when the loop is going to find the specific color (0,204,0), it's going to look the text of the cell : i.e. EXCELLENT (80) and copy/paste the numerical value into the col H. My numbers are going from 0 ; 5; 20 ; 40 ; 60 ; 80 ; 100.

If the loop find two cells with the color (0,204,0) the B column need to be colored (0,0,255)

Finnaly, if the result in the specific text is 0, the col H related need to be colored in (255,0,0).